# Error while installing node package "Strongloop"

Tags: node.js, github, loopbackjs

I am trying to install `strongloop` node package. While installing I got the following error.Is this because of SSH port being blocked?
I have `node` and `npm` installed and working

`Node.js`

```
npm WARN 'git config --get remote.origin.url' returned wrong result (git://githu
b.com/strongloop-forks/passwd-user)

npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/strongloop-forks/passwd-user Cloning into ba
re repository 'C:\Users\RG\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com
-strongloop-forks-passwd-user-3982f620'...

npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/strongloop-forks/passwd-user

npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/strongloop-forks/passwd-user fatal: unable t
o connect to github.com:

npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/strongloop-forks/passwd-user github.com[0: 1
92.30.252.128]: errno=No error

npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:

npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=No error

npm ERR!
npm ERR!

npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:647:15)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
npm ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:966:11)
npm ERR!     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR!     at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600

npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "strongloop"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\RG\Desktop\node
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RG\Desktop\node\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: where is your npm command ?

Comment: I did `npm install -g strongloop` and above this were all the dependencies which were getting downloaded, before it reached this !
I tried cloning the repo and installing `package.json` but had the same problem.
Do you need the whole log(Its quite big)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on your ~/.gitconfig file :

```
[url "http://"]
    insteadOf = ssh://
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for replying late :/